# Unix: Files starting with a dash, -

Tags: bash, unix, rename

Ok, I have a bunch of files starting with a dash, -. Which is not so good... and I want to rename them. In my particular case I would just like to put a character in front of them.

I found the following line that should work, but because of it dash it doesn't:

```
for file in -N*.ext; do mv $file x$file; done
```

If I put an `echo` in front of the `mv` I get a bunch of

```
mv -N1.ext x-f1.ext
mv -N2.ext x-f2.ext
```

Which is correct, except of course it will think the first filename is options. So when I remove the `echo` and run it I just get a bunch of

```
mv: illegal option -- N
```

I have tried to change it to

```
for file in -N*.ext; do mv "$file" "x$file"; done
```

but the quotes are just ignored it seems. Tried to use single quotes, but then the variable wasn't expanded... What do I do here?

**Update:** I have now also tried to quote the quotes. Like this:

```
for file in -N*.ext; do mv '"'$file'"' '"'x$file'"'; done
```

And when I echo that, it looks correct, but when I actually run it I just get

```
mv: rename "-N1.ext" to "x-n1.ext":: No such file or directory
```

I have just no clue how to do this now... *sigh*

Comment: [How to remove a file with name starting with “-r” using cli](https://superuser.com/q/689825/241386), [How to open files with forward dash in linux](https://superuser.com/q/603792/241386), [Can't rename a file the name of which starts with a hyphen](https://superuser.com/q/510337/241386), [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/44425)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use the keyword `--` to tell the *mv* command that the arguments are not to be interpreted as options.  Watch:

```
$ mv -N1.ext x-f1.ext
mv: invalid option -- N
Try `mv --help' for more information.

$ mv -- -N1.ext x-f1.ext
$ ls
x-f1.ext
```

Use `--` *after* all the options on the commandline.  Eg, if you're trying to use the `-i` option to *mv*, it would go *before* `--`:

```
mv -i -- -filename-begins-with-dash newfilename
```

Comment: Aaah. Didn't think about that one at all. In the mean time I found out I could stick `./` in front of the filename as well, which would work. But this is of course an even neater option :)

Comment: @Svish: that's fair, i didn't think about prepending the filename with `./` either.  but you're correct, that works too, for this situation.

Comment: Note that `--` meaning don't process further arguments as options is a convention, and is not respected by all programs. Some use a lone `-` for that, and some don't accepting *anything* for that purpose. So prepending `./` is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @dmckee is right; `--` as a special argument is a GNU extension, but it is mentioned in the POSIX guidelines.  see section 12.2, guideline 10: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html ... this means you can expect most POSIX and GNU utilities to respect the convention, but others may not.

Answer (score 7):

Another technique is to include the parent directory with the file name...

To rename the file `-file-to-rename` to `file-to-rename`...

```
mv  ../parent-dir/-file-to-rename  file-to-rename
```

Credit to @Skippy le Grand Gourou for confirming that `./-file-to-rename` works with `mv` and `rm` as in...

```
mv  ./-file-to-rename  ./--file-to-rename
    
rm  ./-file-to-rename
```

Comment: Or better, as already mentioned in comments to quack quixote's answer, using `./`.