# Removing files with strange names

Tags: command-line, unix, file-management, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix: Files starting with a dash, -](https://superuser.com/questions/120078/unix-files-starting-with-a-dash)

Somehow I ended up with a file named "-r".  How do I remove it?  rm -r doesn't work.  I tried 'rm -i `ls -a`' to step through the file names, but it didn't prompt me to delete this one.

**Edit** A very hacky approach was to use python's os.unlink function.  That worked, but I'm curious to hear other ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man rm`:

> To  remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use one of these commands:
>
> ```
> rm -- -foo
> rm ./-foo
> ```