# How do I delete a file called -v9 on OSX in /root?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix: Files starting with a dash, -](https://superuser.com/questions/120078/unix-files-starting-with-a-dash)

On my OSX (10.6.4) machine, I somehow managed to create a directory called "-v9" in the /var/root directory. How do I delete this directory?

Using the backslash to escape the minus doesn't seem to work:

```
# rm -r \-v9
rm: illegal option -- 9
```

Even using a wildcard won't work:

```
# rm -ri *9
rm: illegal option -- 9
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

I tried to delete it using the Finder, but ran into a different problem. Because it's in the /var/root directory, the Finder won't display the contents of the folder. At least, it doesn't do this by default, and I don't know how to enable it (ditto for Path Finder).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rm -rf ./-v9` or `rm -rf -- -v9`

Comment: The -- is a neat trick.

Answer (score 2):

How about `sudo rm -rf /var/root/-v9`?

Alternatively, check out the [HiddenFiles](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html) Widget, that let's you inspect the contents of hidden folders.

Edit:

1. I just found out Finder won't let you look in `/var/root`, due to permissions - it is owned by System.
2. `/var` is actually a shortcut to `/private/var`, so the above bash command should probably read `sudo rm -rf /private/var/root/-v9`
3. Use these suggestions at your own risk, by the way ;-)

Edit #2: If you use the absolute path to your folder, it doesn't matter that it starts with a '`-`' (at least on my mac). However, if you first `cd` into the relevant directory and type `rm -rf -v9` then `rm` interprets the `-v9` part as an (illegal) argument passed to it.

Cheers