# How do I remove a file in Linux whose name looks like it's ONLY a hyphen, as in "-"

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I've tried

```
rm -- -
rm "-"
rm "\-"
rm \-
```

Gave Perl a shot

```
~$ perl -e '$junk = glob("-"); chomp $junk; print "$junk\n"; `rm $junk`;'
-
rm: cannot remove `-': No such file or directory
```

...and...

```
~$ perl -e '$junk = glob("-"); chomp $junk; print "$junk\n"; `mv $junk newfile.garbage`;'
-
mv: cannot stat `-': No such file or directory
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated, wise folks.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did it get there?

Comment: It was the result of a poorly constructed wget: "wget -q -O – http://www.someserver.org/s/ip"

Comment: Reminds me of the time a colleague created a file named * . This story did not end well.

Comment: What `rm` version are you using (`rm --version`)? `rm -` works fine with GNU coreutils 8.5.

Comment: fyi, zipping from a pipe also produces a file with the same name.. although I don't recall it being difficult to delete.

Comment: From your reply below, I would say there is no such file.

Comment: First thing I'd do is `ls` to a file and then use a hex editor on the file to see what the name really is.  Then write a simple Java program to do File.delete of the named file.

Comment: Another variant: `rm ./-`

Comment: [Files starting with a dash, -](https://superuser.com/q/120078/241386), [How to open files with forward dash in linux](https://superuser.com/q/603792/241386), [How to create a file which is named like a command line argument?](https://superuser.com/q/600066/241386), [Recursively rename all files whose name starts with a dash](https://askubuntu.com/q/882773/253474), [Can't rename a file the name of which starts with a hyphen](https://superuser.com/q/510337/241386), [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/44425)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This used to be posted in the Usenet FAQs for Unix—I see it is in the [GNU Core Utility FAQs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#How-do-I-remove-files-that-start-with-a-dash_003f).  There were at least five different methods, but this works well:

```
$ rm ./-
```

If a filename contains untypeable characters, then use:

```
$ rm -i *
```

The `-i` flag asks for confirmation for each file if it should be removed or not.

Comment: Or rm -i -- '*-*' if you are looking for files containing a dash and maybe some spaces or whatever.

Comment: rm -i * also worked for me.  Thanks wallyk!

Answer (score 39):

Removing a file whose names starts with `-` is a FAQ, but it looks like you've got a different problem.

Of the solutions you mentioned in the question:

```
rm -- -
```

That should work.

```
rm "-"
```

That's no different from `rm -`.  The quotes are stripped by the shell, and the `rm` command just sees the single hyphen as an argument.  Quotation marks are useful for escaping shell metacharacters; the hyphen is special to `rm`, not to the shell.

```
rm "\-"
```

The quotation marks escape the backslash, so this attempts to remove a file whose name consists of two characters, a backslash and a hyphen.

```
rm \-
```

This is just like `rm "-"`, equivalent to `rm -`.

As it happens, at least with the GNU coreutils version of `rm`, `rm -` actually removes (or attempts to remove) a file whose name consists of just a hyphen.  If your file had that name, it would be gone by now.  I conclude that your file has a name that only *looks like* a hyphen.

```
ls | cat -A
```

should give an idea of what it's really called.

Here's a Perl script I just threw together that will prompt you for each file in the current directory and ask whether to remove it.  Offered without warranty, but I've tested it briefly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

opendir my $DIR, '.' or die ".: $!\n";
my @files = sort grep { -f $_ } readdir $DIR;
closedir $DIR;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    print "Remove $file? ";
    my $answer = scalar <>;
    if ($answer =~ /^[Yy]/) {
        unlink $file or warn "$file: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($answer =~ /^[Qq]/) {
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: A less elaborate solution: if the file's name is just one character, then `rm ?` should remove it (along with any other such files).

Comment: thank you, that script did the trick.  The actual filename from: ls | cat -A looked like this: M-bM-^@M-^S$   Very strange

Comment: `M-bM-^@M-^S` is a rendition of the 3-byte UTF-8 representation of the Unicode "EN DASH" character, 0x2013.  I wonder if you accidentally copy-and-pasted it from a web page.

Comment: did `rm -i *` not work? Seems like it would do the same thing as the perl script.

Comment: I'm guessing it originated from the web page at which I pointed the wget.  In any case, thanks again for the thorough solution!  take care.

Comment: perl -e 'unlink grep { print "remove $_? "; <STDIN> =~ /y/i } glob "*"'

Comment: @RandalSchwartz: Impressively terse (and makes my brain hurt a bit) -- but I'd want `/^y/i` rather than `/y/i`.  After all, a Russian user might type "Nyet".

Comment: find -name - -delete

Comment: @JuicyScripter: The file's name isn't `"-"`.

Comment: The edit is wrong: rm ? does not work for a file with one dash for the same reason that rm "-" does not work - the shell expands ? to - and rm - is called. You need to do rm -- ?

Comment: (1) The file's name isn't a hyphen; that's the whole point of the question.  (2) At least for GNU coreutils rm, `rm -` does work for a file named `-`.

Comment: (3) And `rm ?`, at least on my system (Ubuntu 11.04), does work to remove the file in question (whose name is an "en-dash" character, not a hyphen).

Comment: I just tested and found that "rm -i *" also worked.  Thanks again

Answer (score 19):

If you want something safer...

Try using a combination of ls and find (this works for any file you have permission to remove)

The '-i' parameter will give you the inode number for each directory entry
ls -li

```
27 ----------  1 owner  group       3981 Oct 11 04:42 ?????
```

Once you have the inode number...

```
find . -inum **27** -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: +1 as this is a great general answer for these problems. By the way theres no need to used -exec rm in recent find's, just use -delete

Comment: @Sirex - I think the point of `-exec rm -i {}` is the `-i` to prompt for removal. I'm looking at `man find` and don't see any way to do that.

Comment: oh yes, in this case. was more of a tip.

Answer (score 13):

Give `rm ./-` a try.

The `-` is a flag to start a flag argument. If you start the argument with anything but a `-`, in this case `/`, it will assume it's the file name. Which is what you wish.

And since `file` and `./file` are the same file, it will target the file named `-` via `./-`.

Comment: Rather than typing 30 characters, perhaps it would have been more useful to explain why the / helps parse correctly

Comment: @gcb Thanks for the proposed edit. I added code markup to that, so it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
$ ls -b
```

to see if the filename has unprintable characters.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Given the [followup](http://superuser.com/questions/347505/how-do-i-remove-a-file-in-linux-whose-name-looks-like-its-only-a-hyphen-as-in/347544#347544), this sounds like a very good suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Not as geeky as most other answers, but I would fire up an instance of `mc`, midnight commander, and just select and delete the file.

Comment: +1 for cleverly side-stepping the issue - and that without even resorting to a GUI program.

Answer (score 6):

Not that it should be necessary to use perl here, but this should work:

```
perl -e 'unlink "-"'
```

or to see what any error with the above might be:

```
perl -e 'unlink "-" or die "Err: $!"'
```

Comment: This method has the advantage that there are no special characters to worry about (other than string quoting issues).

Answer (score 3):

I have had luck using GNOME's Nautilus to remove badly named files. Are you running an X-server? I'm sure other file browsers would work too.

Answer (score 3):

If

```
rm -- -
```

didn't work, the file name is not "just a hyphen". If no other files have a hyphen in them, you could try

```
perl -E'for (@_) { if (/-/) { unlink($_) or die $! } }' -- *
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I get a "No such file or directory" for every method posted so far:

```
rm ./-
rm -- -
mv "-" test.txt
rm -rf '-' <-- this gives no error, but doesn't work
perl -e 'unlink "-";'  <--also no error, doesn't work.
```

It appears I've got rm version 7.4.  I'll try upgrading and re-attempting these suggestions.  Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is no such file or directory, and perhaps the file name also contains some invisible character(s). (and you could get about the same error message in perl with 'unlink "-" or die "Err: $!"'). Try "ls -b" to see what the real filename is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very fond of using `dired` mode in emacs for this kind of thing -- just "open" the directory in emacs. You can easily select files and mark them for deletion.

Another poster suggested using midnight commander; this is pretty much the same idea, but if you're already an emacs user it's perhaps more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do `rm -f '-'` worked for me in cygwin

For that matter, `rm -` also seems to work on red hat.

Comment: in Ubuntu: 
~/jj$ rm -rf '-'
~/jj$ ls
–

Comment: `rm -` works for me too.

Comment: Why -r ? Requesting a recursive deletion if you don't need it is always dangerous in case of mispelings.

Comment: @hstoerr, good point.  just habbit.  hands type faster than brain.  editing response now, thanks.