# Should we systematically use `--` when executing `rm`?

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, script

A question about the recommended usage of rm and `--`

Let's say I've created two files `-i` and `xx`. If I try to remove them with

```
$ rm *
```

I get:

```
rm: remove regular file `xx'? n
```

And, as explained in [How do I remove a file in Linux whose name looks like it's ONLY a hyphen, as in "-"](https://superuser.com/questions/347505/how-do-i-remove-a-file-in-linux-whose-name-looks-like-its-only-a-hyphen-as-in) and others, the way of solving this is with:

```
$ rm -- *
```

Obviously the problems could possibly be much worse with names called `-rf` or similar.

So my question is:

> Should we systematically use `--` in `rm` commands before anything that is expandable, to avoid unpleasant surprises or exploits?

The reason I ask this is that a while ago I learnt this `rm` gotcha and then forgot it, until recently that a teammate brought it in again. However I have never seen any recommendations in that sense and being so risky, I wonder if we should have it more present? Should the usage of `--` be some kind of scripting and console pattern whenever using `rm` (and probably other commands)?

Comment: It would be a good idea but usually isn't necessary. If you would like to make your script more robust I would include it. The -- just means no more options will follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a perfect world, I guess yes, we should systematically use `--`. But we all learned to use the `rm` command without systematically typing `--`, and typing it costs three extra keystrokes so I don't see it happening. Plus, the `--` convention to terminate options hasn't always existed (which is why many people didn't learn about it back when they learned how to use `rm`).

That being said, when using `rm` (and other commands) in shell scripts, you definitely should always program defensively. So for example:

```
rm "$1"    # Remove the file named in the first command line argument
```

is unsafe and should be `rm -- "$1"`. However,

```
rm "/var/spool/foo/$thatfile"
```

is safe, because the contents of `$thatfile` cannot cause `rm` to misinterpret its arguments.

In your specific example (`rm *`), I would probably usually use `rm ./*` as a safe workaround.