# How to remove a file with name starting with "-r" using cli

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, rm

I have been creating odd-named files every once in a while, e.g.

```
$ls -rthl
$-rw-r--r--  1 shamil hep  290 Aug 13 11:58 -rf
```

And interestingly it is impossible to remove this file with

```
rm -f -rf
```

I know I need to escape the special symbols like "-", so the issue is clear. And I used to know the solution, but have since forgotten.

How do I properly delete it?

I have tried things like this

```
rm -f \-rf
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Ty. Somehow I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Probably best to just haul out the big guns `python -c 'import os; os.remove("-rf")'`

Comment: @U2EF1 nice. I used to use that hack before learning the `--` :) Sadly, not every distribution has Python, so it is also not very portable.

Comment: Even more discussion at [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/23408) (on U&L).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`--` switch means: *End of flags, everything after it is assumed to be a file name*. So you can do:

```
rm -- -rf
```

Include the full path to the file also works:

```
rm /full/path/to/-rf
```

Actually, this is kind of hilarious but this command line can give you the answer :)

```
$man rm | cat | grep -B4 -A3 -- "rm --"

To remove a file whose name starts with a `-', for example `-foo', use 
one of these commands:

rm -- -foo
rm ./-foo
```

Comment: This won't work with all commands.

Comment: Please can you provide an example? I was quoting the `man bash` there.

Comment: @PauloBu `man rm` in `bash`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist not, actually I quote `man bash`. But seeing `man rm` there is a line that tells you that: `man rm |cat |grep -B4 -A3 -- "rm --"`

Comment: The double dash trick is handled by the command line processing library. It is not guaranteed to work all of the time. Try this script `#!/bin/sh

for i in $@
do
 echo $i
done`

Comment: @Donovan `--` works with all commands that respect the option parsing conventions, which is almost all of them.

Comment: @SeanPerry This script doesn't accept any options. (It's also missing some essential quoting, to do something halfway sensible.) Almost all commands do accept options and do obey the [conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02).

Comment: Whether this convention works with all commands is irrelevant, and a different answer to a different question.  **The questioner specifically asked about `rm` and deleting files** and a way to invoke `rm` that xe had forgotten.  Paulo Bu's answer deals specifically with that, even quoting the manual for `rm` where the questioner would have found xyr answer.  Its major problem is a Useless Use Of `cat`.  (-:

Comment: I also offered another alternative which might work whether the shell support `--` or not. That is the full path. Anyways, I hope someone find my answer useful :)

Answer (score 9):

You can do

```
rm -rf ./-rf
```

This will make it so that `-rf` does not start with a `-`.

Answer (score 2):

another way:

```
find -name "-rf" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: This relies on undocumented behavior of `find` -- do you have any information regarding how many variants of *nix support it? Anyway, it’s just a roundabout way of saying `rm ./-rf`.

Comment: @Scott `find` without a directory argument is specific to Linux (both GNU and BusyBox) and is equivalent to `find .`. The names listed by `find .` obviously don't start with `-` since they start with `./`.

Comment: But that’s my point – how do you know that `find . … -exec …` _builds command arguments_ beginning with `./`? Sure, you might guess that it does, from the behavior of `find . … -print` (in contrast to, for example, `ls .` or `ls -l .`), and maybe it is standard, but it’s not documented.