# How to copy a file with a $ (dollar sign) in the name from one folder to another in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, file-transfer

I have a file which I want to copy from one directory to another directory.

Suppose that's the file `some.txt` to copy from folder1 to folder2

```
cp -r some.txt /folder2
```

I am able to copy this file but if the filename start with `$` like `$somefile.class` then I am not able to copy the file, just getting file not exist error

```
cp -r $somefile.class /folder2
```

Answer (score 16):

First of all, you don't need the `-r` flag which is (from `man cp`):

> `-R`, `-r`, `--recursive`
>           copy directories recursively

That is only useful when copying entire directories and their contents. Then, whenever your file names contain strange characters, you need to either escape them or protect them with single quotes as the other answers have already suggested:

```
cp '$somefile.class' /folder2
cp \$somefile.class /folder2
```

Alternatively, you can use the shell's glob expansion feature to copy the file:

```
cp ?somefile.class /folder2
cp *somefile.class /folder2
```

The `?` matches "any single character" and `*` matches "0 or more characters". So, using these globs will allow you to copy the target file without worrying about the name. However, bear in mind that you should use this carefully and make sure that the globs *only* match the file you want to copy. For example, the ones I used would also match `Lsomefile.class`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to [escape](http://linuxg.net/escaping-special-characters-in-linux-and-unix-with-7-practical-examples/) any special character with backslash `\`

```
cp -r \$somefile.class /folder2
```

Read more about [escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) here:

[What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/44425)

Answer (score 8):

The `$` character is used to signify a shell variable. If you file really starts with `$` you should use single-quotes to prevent the shell from attempting to evaluate it as a variable:

```
cp -r '$somefile.class' /folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me in the case that the special character `-` was in front. The only thing that worked for me in that case was placing the current directory in front like this:

```
cp -r './-somefile.class' /folder2
```

Although it is not the `$` sign, it's a special character and it might help some other people out there. The other solutions did not work such as putting \ before  or placing single or double emphasis around the filename.

Comment: it's irrelevant here. It's the duplicate of various other questions like [Files starting with a dash](https://superuser.com/q/120078/241386), [create a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/44425), [How to cd into a directory with this name “-2” (starting with the hyphen)?](https://serverfault.com/q/462739/343888), [How do I deal with a filename that starts with the hyphen (-) character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5677558/995714), [create a file which is named like a command line argument?](https://superuser.com/q/600066/241386)