# How can I remove a file or directory called "\"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, rm

I'm using terminal on a Ubuntu machine and there is a file that I would like to delete.  The file's name is `\` (just a backslash).

Now usually I would just do

```
rm filename
```

However if I do `rm \` then it thinks I'm trying to write a multi-line command.

How can I delete this file?  I know that I could just use the GUI file system, but that's not very efficient.

So, how can I delete (in terminal) a file called `\`?

Comment: This requires the escape character, see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix: Files starting with a dash, -](http://superuser.com/questions/120078/unix-files-starting-with-a-dash)

Comment: Why do you have a file named that?  (It doesn't even let me put it in a `code` block here in this comment!)

Comment: More fun is trying to delete a file called <BEL>, aka Ctrl-G if I recall correctly. Everytime you do a **ls** the keyboard beeps at you until you (a) discovered the *invisible* file; and (b) determined how to delete a file with only one unprintable character in its name.

Comment: More importantly, how do you delete a file named "/" ?

Comment: @Curt `fsck`.  Seriously.  If a file named `/` exists, your filesystem is corrupt.

Comment: I always liked the file named `*` myself...

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens, +10, I shall try this! How do you create a file with the name of unprintable character?

Comment: @Vorac: Now that you know it is possible - figure it out yourself. It's the **knowing it's possible** that is the real challenge; the rest is just good clean fun.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `rm \\` (escape the backslash with another backslash).  Note that this also works similarily, for directories named `\` (using either `rmdir`, or `rm` with the `-r` flag).

Example:

```
>mkdir demo
>cd demo
>touch \\
>ls -l
total 0
-rw-------  1 hennes  users  0 Jul 29 20:25 \
>rm \\
>ls -l
total 0
```

Comment: Or, under the same principle, `rm '\'` (but *not* `rm "\"`).

Comment: @evilsoup just to provide some additional clarification on that, the `\ ` character is used as an escape character in double-quote delimited strings.  Saying `rm "\"` will be parsed into an unclosed string, as the second quotation mark is used with an escape character (and thus will be parsed as the double-quote character itself, and **not** the end of a string).  Thus, the terminal will wait until you finish the string with another `"`.  The equivalent method to use double quotes here would be `rm "\\"` (which is directly equivalent to both `rm '\'` and `rm \\ `, as you already confirmed).

Answer (score 16):

A general tactic for manually deleting files with awkward characters in their names is

```
rm -i ./*
```

This will prompt you to choose whether or not to delete each file in the directory.

Comment: Or, single it was a single char. `rm -i ./?`

Comment: Yeah.  If you can write a more specific glob than ./*, that's always a good idea, especially when doing something destructive.

Comment: +1 for prefixing your glob with `./`

Answer (score 12):

You can also unlink by referencing the inode of a file

```
linus ~/test $ touch \\
linus ~/test $ ls -li
total 0
15204561 -rw-r--r-- 1 pat sudo 0 Jul 29 23:03 \
linus ~/test $ find . -inum 15204561 -exec rm -v {} \;
removed `./\\'
linus ~/test $ ls -li
total 0
linus ~/test $
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check inode of file first .
ls -li

137791 -rw-rw-r--. 1 svr svr   366 Mar 11 15:57

inode of "\" is "137791 and then use find command to delete "\" with inode number.

find . -inum 137791 -exec rm -i {} \;

rm: remove regular file `./\'? yes

"\" will be removed then.

Comment: Best answer! Works!